# Binding EventToCommand inside of Style

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

I have a style of LongListBoxItem, each item has a picture and description. So, different events should be called, depends on the touched object (either pic or desc). I'm using Mvvmlight.

The problem is that i'm totally lost in event cases and event parameters. I'm trying different events:

---

Tap event + PassEventArgsToCommand = returns GestureEventArgs, not sure if i'd be able to extract item id from there

SelectedItem event + PassEventArgsToCommand = returns SelectionChangedEventArgs, but never fires (maybe because event is rising not from listbox item, but from its childern, border)

Tap event + CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ProductCategoriesListBox}" = cant find Elementname from the style, as i'm going to use it multiple times

SelectedItem event + CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ProductCategoriesListBox}" = well, the same thing

---

Maybe there's better approach for my task?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so TemplatedParent is to the resque in this case (line 5).

```
    <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
        <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
            <command:EventToCommand 
                Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}, Path=NavigationViewModel.OnTapItemCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=DataContext}"/>
        </interactivity:EventTrigger>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Now it it possible to have access to listbox items from the style.